# libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

Tags: linux, gnome, nvidia, intel

When trying to run `gnome-control-center`, I get the following errors:

```
libEGL warning: DRI3: Screen seems not DRI3 capable
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
```

`gnome-control-center` then proceeds to not open. Running it with `sudo` will result in a blank window opening. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, updating and upgrading my system, but nothing seems to work.

I'm running Zorin 15 Bionic on a i5-6200U, with a NVIDIA GTX 940M GPU.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are not fatal, they're logged even when the `gnome-control-center` runs properly.

Have you tried reinstalling `gnome-control-center`? It helped me to solve this problem, so it might also help you:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center --reinstall
```

I think you are experiencing the same problem as is described here:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411379/ubuntu-22-04-gnome-control-center-or-gnome-system-settings-not-opening